# What is the Windows API equivalent for Windows PS commands Get-VM, Get-VMProcessor, Get-Counter

Tags: powershell, api

Is there a thumb rule to search for the API equivalent of a Windows Powershell command? I was hoping MSFT would put in the documentation of the PS command. 
I need API which I can use in my C++ to do what Get-VM, Get-VMProcessor, Get-Counter PS commands do. For example Get-Process is a PS command and EnumProcesses() is the API equivalent. If I can get similar equivalent for the three API and a general thumb rule if one exists that would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by API equivalent of powershell?

Comment: As I said for  For example Get-Process is a PS command and EnumProcesses() is the API which we can use pro grammatically in a C++ program. So what would be the one for Get-VM, Get-VMProcessor and Get-Counter. I understand there usually are minimum 2 APIs/PS command, the first one to get a handle and the second one will actually get  the desired data. If I get the actual API then figuring out the dependent API is easy.

Comment: You can use vmware's VI3 API  , look there [apis](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk25pubs/ReferenceGuide/)

Comment: Thank you Vad but unfortunately I need Microsoft Windows API's :(